# How to access MS Word table properties to change the size in percent

Tags: python, winapi, automation, ms-word, docx

I would like to access the properties of a table object within a Word document (docx or doc format).

And change the `preferred width` and `Measure in:` options within multiple documents. [image: Table properties]

You can access this window in Word by right-clicking the table and picking the `table properties`

Any ideas how should I approach this?

Comment: Have you verified whether this is reflected as a document property (on the table) as opposed to a setting in MS Word only, that affects how tables are generated but not actually stored in the document?

Answer (score 0):

I should have dug deeper into [Word object model documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/word-object-model-overview?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp)

```
import win32com.client
word = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
doc = word.Documents.Open(path)
doc.Activate()

for index, table in enumerate(word.ActiveDocument.Tables):
            if index == 0:
                # print(table)
                table.PreferredWidthType = 2
                table.PreferredWidth = 100
```